# Android: upload photos

Tags: android, upload, photo

Greetings,

I'm having trouble uploading a photo from my Android phone. Here is the code I'm using to prompt the user to select a photo:

```
public class Uploader{
        public void upload(){
            Log.i("EOH","hi...");
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
        }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                //what do do now with this Bitmap...
                    //how do I upload it?




            }
        }

    }
```

So I have the Bitmap b, however I don't know what to do next?

I have the following code for sending POST requests:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("someValA", String.valueOf(lat)));  
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("someValB", String.valueOf(lng)));  
new HttpConnection(handler).post("http://myurl.com/upload.php",params);
```

How can I hook up a Bitmap image to this? I've searched google for ages and can't find a good way of doing it.

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

---

Ok I've tried chirag shah's suggestion. Here is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri imageUri=data.getData();
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageUri.getPath()));
                post("http://www.myurl.com/ajax/uploadPhoto.php",params);
            }
        }
```

where the post function (as recommended) is:

```
public void post(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            try {
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                for(int index=0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
                    if(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
                        // If the key equals to "image", we use FileBody to transfer the data
                        entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new FileBody(new File (nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue())));
                    }else{
                        // Normal string data
                        entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));
                    }
                }

                httpPost.setEntity(entity);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                Log.i("EOH",response.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

However myurl.com/ajax/uploadPhoto.php is getting nothing. I've created a PHP log to log any activity on uploadPhoto.php, and nothing is showing up. It's worth noting that if I just type myurl.com/ajax/uploadPhoto.php straight into a web browser, it logs fine.

Any more suggestions?

Many thanks,

Comment: I've found that http posts must be done from an Async task otherwise they just won't happen. I've been looking at doing something similar both posting and getting data and needed to wrap the posts to the url in an async task. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't already. Try wrapping the post to the server in an Async Task and calling the task. I found that the api I am using requires http posts/gets to be done away from the main thread to avoid possible issues locking up the main thread.

It was relatively easy just to set it up as an Async task and that started actually working.

More info on Async tasks : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

For a simple example this is one of my async tasks :

```
private class SomeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        UserFunctions uf = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject res = uf.doPostToServer(arg0[0], arg0[1], arg0[2], getApplicationContext());

        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

        try {
            int success = result.getInt("success");
            if(success == 1) {

                Intent vcact = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtherActivity.class);
                vcact.putExtra("id", cid);
                startActivity(vcact);
                // close main screen
                finish();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SomeActivity.this, "Error saving to server. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and it is called onclick with

```
new SomeAsyncTask().execute(cid, otherdata, moredata);
```

Comment: The actual post is done in uf.doPostToServer... I think you're on the right track there just try making it async and see if it helps. It did for me.